# Retain bit-exact floating point calculations on AArch64 with O2

Tags: c, gcc, arm, arm64, fpu

I'm comparing outputs of signal processing library using floating-point math, which was built for AArch64 (ARMv8) using e.g. gcc 4.9.

Differences occur depending on the optimization level. Unoptimized builds (O0) calculate bit-exact results with respect to an ARMv7 reference. In ARMv7 environments 'O2' builds did not introduce deviations in the floating point calculations.
This is not the case for ARMv8. Optimized builds actually calculate a different result.

Are compiler switches available to retain bit-exactness to non-optimized builds?

Tests have been performed on a DragonBoard 410c (Cortex-A53).

Comment: The hardware performs the FP ops the same. The differences you're seeing are probably due to the introduction of SIMD operations which can change the number of total floating point ops. For example, if you're adding a list of numbers one at a time you'll get a different result from adding them 4 by 4 and then summing the last 4 as the final step. Each FP operation introduces a slight error; the more you use, the larger the error.

Comment: I know that floating point associativity is critical. Still compilers for ARMv7 were able to ensure bit-perfect processing even with O2 active. Now at least with my first tests on the DragonBoard, this doesn't seem to be the case for ARMv8. Could be a hardware glitch or compiler property (or intended behavior).

Comment: The most likely explanation for the differences is that floating point registers are sometimes larger than a `double` for instance.  When optimized, the compiler will often keep intermediate results in floating point registers, with the effect that the result is more accurate than, but different from, the result obtained when the values are stored to memory.  If you're using `gcc`, try specifying this option:  `-ffloat-store`  This will inhibit most of the optimizations that could result in changes to floating point results.

Comment: Better yet - if you really care about how the FP ops are done, write the code in assembly language. Giving your code to a compiler and expecting different CPU/optimization options to produce the same FP results will disappoint you every time.

Comment: P.S. Bit-exactness is something achievable with integer math. For floating point math, a better goal would be "margin of error".

Comment: On armv7, optimization settings less than `-Ofast` must use VFP floating-point instructions, because NEON doesn't have ieee754 compliance (treats denormals as zero). On armv8, NEON supports ieee754, so the compiler can use it.

Comment: Thanks EOF, that's a useful hint. However that would mean that NEON optimizations on ARMv8 would support denormals and thus should stay bit-exact to non-optimized processing.

Comment: @nucleon: Depending on `FP_CONTRACT`, the compiler may be using fused-multiply-add instructions that avoid intermediate rounding. This could produce non bitwise-identical results while remaining ieee754 compliant. NEON on armv8 has these FMA-instruction by default, VFP needs to be vfpv4 to include them. Did you compile with `mfpu=vfpv4`?

Comment: @EOF The AArch64 toolchain doesn't support `mfpu=vfpv4`. But FMA-instructions could be an explanation.

Comment: To clear up some of these comments... GCC will not re-associate FP math at `-O2` unless you give it one of the relaxing `-ffast-math` options. AArch64 does not calculate 64-bit floating point in a wider register mode (so `-ffloat-store` won't help), and a C compiler *can* be relied upon to produce portable results between optimisation levels and architectures (as long as you are not in a mode which relaxes the standard). ARMv8-A supports full IEEE754 in Neon, but only in AArch64 mode. The most likely issue here is FMA instructions. Try setting `-ffp-contract=off`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your options to your ARMv7-A builds (If you were using `-mfpu=vfpv4` or equivalent, this answer is probably wrong) the most likely difference you are seeing will be the generation of FMA operations.

To avoid this, use `-ffp-contract=off`. The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) for this option says:

> `-ffp-contract=style`
>
> `-ffp-contract=off` disables floating-point expression contraction.
>
> `-ffp-contract=fast` enables floating-point expression contraction such
>   as forming of fused multiply-add operations if the target has native
>   support for them.
>
> `-ffp-contract=on` enables floating-point expression
>   contraction if allowed by the language standard. This is currently not
>   implemented and treated equal to `-ffp-contract=off`.
>
> The default is `-ffp-contract=fast`.